# Text I am drawing to HTML is blinking p5js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I am assuming this is because the draw loop is drawing every x amount of seconds.

How can I slow it down or prevent it from updating every frame without slowing down the video refresh rate.

My thought was to add an fps counter and check `if (fps_counter >= 60)` update html?

See the last block of code 'getResult()'

```
// see gotResult()
function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 260);
  // Create the video
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(320, 240);
  video.hide();
  // frameRate(5);

  flippedVideo = ml5.flipImage(video)
  // Start classifying
  classifyVideo();
}
```

```
// see gotResult()
function draw() {
  background(0);
  // Draw the video
  image(flippedVideo, 0, 0);

  // Draw the label
  fill(255);
  textSize(25);
  textAlign(CENTER);
}
```

```
// I believe the issue is here.
// HTML is noticeably blinking.
function gotResult(error, results) {
    $("#background").html("✅ | " + parseInt(results[0].confidence * 100) + "%");
    $("#cardboard-paper").html(" | " + parseInt(results[1].confidence * 100) + "%");
    $("#plastic").html(" | " + parseInt(results[2].confidence * 100) + "%");
    $("#can").html(" | " + parseInt(results[3].confidence * 100) + "%");

  classifyVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by blinking, but p5.js has a built-in frame counter, the `frameCount` variable. You can read more in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameCount).

You can use this along with the modulus `%` operator to trigger some behavior every X frames. Something like this:

```js
// only do the thing once per second
if(frameCount % 60 == 0) {
  // do the thing
}
```